# Assembly: subroutines and PUSH/POP

Tags: assembly, arm, subroutine

Hi guys I'm having trouble with the assembly language code. I'm trying to use the stack to pass the parameter to the subroutine, but here is something I can't solve:

```
...some other code...
FindMin: PUSH {R2} ;FindMin is a loop
         BL ELEMENT  ;ELEMENT is used to read the value
         MOV R6,R5
         PUSH {R3}   ;R3 contains the address of Dj
         BL ELEMENT
...other part of the code...
```

And my ELEMENT is like this:

```
ELEMENT:
    POP {R4}
    LDR R5,[R4]
    BX LR
```

I traced the program and right after PUSH {R3} is executed, instead of proceeding to BL ELEMENT, the program will go back to PUSH {R2}. It will continue this infinite loop. I don't know why it works like this. Can you guys give some advice?

Comment: You should add a tag for the appropriate assembly language or mention it in the title if a tag doesn't exist, it will help get you better answers.

Comment: Don't see how that could happen. Make sure you are debugging the correct program and not some previous build or something.

Comment: If this is bare-metal/simulator stuff, where is it loaded, and how much "other code" is beforehand, i.e. does `push r2` happen to be located at, say, the address of the data abort vector?